# How can I repair a leaking drip coffee brewer?

Tags: coffee-machines

My drip coffee brewer's container has been cracked and it is leaking. I know super glue is toxic. How can I repair it?

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a few additional details (e.g. what material are we talking about) and maybe a photo or two? As it stands, it’s either too broad or unclear. The [help] will explain more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

Just get a replacement. Given reality, unless it's some super special-to-you drip brewer, get a whole replacement coffee maker, which will set you back very little at all at a thrift store, and not much more brand-new. Finding the exact replacement for a particular carafe is much more difficult, and often, in the odd way things are, more expensive.

If you simply HAVE to repair it, well, either go visit a glassblower, or become one (assuming a glass carafe - replace "glassblower" with "weldor" if a stainless steel carafe that you've somehow managed to crack.) That will undoubtely cost a great deal more.

I've personally moved away from automatic drip, but things are no different in French press - if you break the glass, the whole thing costs less than getting a replacement for just the glass. So far I've managed "careful" pretty well (mine is is probably older than I am,) but I know a fair number of folks who've gone to a stainless steel French press after dropping a couple of glass ones.